# React: Passing props to Component's inner function fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm testing if it is possible to have a Button component which changes a 'counter' state, but the nature of the change depends on another state 'type'. Doing console log of the prop 'type' inside the Button component it appears to get correctly the content of it, but when passing it to a inner funtion 'handler', it turns to 'undefined'. Any idea of why this happens?

[App.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3fjh.png)

[Button.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ukBv.png)

[Input.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC4Dk.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
const handler = (type, setCounter) =>`
```

Comment: You're right! it now works! but why though? why it didn't work as "const handler = ({type, setCounter}) =>" ?

Comment: Because you called it like `handler(type, setCounter)` and not `handler({ type, setCounter })`

Comment: Now I get, the props of a Component is an object, and I was treating the parameters of the function 'handler' also as an object. Thanks for that!